# The Witches: A Discworld Board Game - Defeating Count Bela

Tags: scoring, discworld-the-witches

When you defeat Count Bela Magpyr, the rules says that all Magpyr figures are removed from the board. What will happen with the points in that cards? Are for the player who defeat Bela or just are removed from the game (points go for no one)?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The removal of all other Magpyrs is part of the special reward for defeating the Count. Player who defeated him gets to keep his token and score the points just for him, all other are simply set aside and no one gets the points for them.